# Сортировка в go

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, golang, структуры-данных

Go позволяет сортировать целые числа. При этом, возникает проблема с сортировкой строк:

```
strs := []string{"c", "a", "b"}
sort.Strings(strs)
fmt.Println("Strings:", strs)
```

Сортировка чисел в `golang` может выглядеть так:

```
ints := []int{7, 2, 4}
sort.Ints(ints)
fmt.Println("Ints:   ", ints)
```

Примеры взяты [отсюла](https://gobyexample.com/sorting)

Также можно использовать callback функции:

```
// Данная функция сортирует PairList
func SortByValue(wordFrequencies PairList) PairList {
    pl := make(PairList, len(wordFrequencies))
    i := 0
    for _, v := range wordFrequencies {
        pl[i] = Pair{v.Key, v.WeightWay}
        i++
    }
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(pl))
    return pl
}

type PairList []Pair

type Pair struct {
    Key int
    WeightWay float64
    WeightWay2 float64
}


// Операторы
func (p PairList) Len() int { return len(p) }
func (p PairList) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i].WeightWay < p[j].WeightWay }
func (p PairList) Swap(i, j int){ p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }
```

Но как быть, если я хочу сортировать в одном случае по `WeightWay`, в другом -- по `WeightWay2`? Мне каждый раз пересоздавать структуру? Вряд ли это хорошее решение. Подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Go 1.8 можете использовать [`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice):

```
people := []struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}{
    {"Gopher", 7},
    {"Alice", 55},
    {"Vera", 24},
    {"Bob", 75},
}
sort.Slice(people, func(i, j int) bool { return people[i].Name < people[j].Name })
fmt.Println("By name:", people)

sort.Slice(people, func(i, j int) bool { return people[i].Age < people[j].Age })
fmt.Println("By age:", people)
```

Comment: Что в более ранних версия? Подобных возможностей нет в 1.6?

Comment: @hedgehogues Нет. Там пишите типы.